# Constant function in PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? I defined a constant named 'VALUE' and its value is 'STAR', then I created a variable `$var = 10;` and I used constant function in this line:

```
$data = constant ('VALUE'. $var);
```

and I decided to echo the program

```
echo VALUE10;
```

and I encountered this errors :

[image]

The code :

```
<?php
define ('VALUE' , 'STAR');
$var = 10;
$data = constant ('VALUE'. $var);
echo VALUE10;
?>
```

Comment: The code you provided is not the one that triggered an error.

Comment: `constant`  returns the value of a defined constant. It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: So what is the cause of the errors

Comment: I'm not forced to do this , but it is an instance in the book am reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some errors there.
First, the 'constant' function is not used to create constansts, but only to get the value of existing constants: [read the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)

Second, you should not use quotes around constants, or else they will be just strings.

Third, your logic is wrong.

I think you tried to do this:

```
<?php
define('VALUE', 'STAR');
$var = 10;
define(VALUE . $var, 'some value');
$data = constant(VALUE . $var);
echo $data;
echo STAR10; // same as above
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The constant function is used for getting the value of a defined constant. To define a constant use the define function.

```
bool define ( string $name , mixed $value [, bool $case_insensitive = false ] )
```

constant() is unnecessary, all you have to write is the constants name:

```
define("TEST_CONSTANT", 24, false);
echo TEST_CONSTANT;
```

If you want to check if a constant has been defined use defined()

```
if(defined("TEST_CONSTANT")) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.

### Edit:

Andre pointed out that the constant function is useful when you don't know the exact name of the constant:

```
define("TEST_" . $value, "stuff");
echo constant("TEST_" . $value);
```

Thanks andre.

Comment: the 'constant()' function is very good when you don't know the exact name of the constant.
define('MY_CONSTANT_' . $some_variable, $some_value);
constant('MY_CONSTANT_' . $some_variable);